# CSS animate não pára no último keyframe

Tags: css

Eu fiz uma simples animação com keyframe e ao executar ele não pára no 100% e sim volta no início da minha animação CSS, vejam:

```
 .mostramenu

{
animation: desce 2s;
-webkit-animation: desce 2s;

}

@keyframes desce {

0% {
margin-top: -70px;

}


100% {
margin-top: 1px;

}


}
```

O que pode estar errado? testei em vários navegadores e também ajustando `-webkit-`

Testei também o FROM - TO

```
@keyframes desce {
  from {
    margin-top: -70px;
}

 to {
margin-top: 1px;
 }

}
```

Comment: Da pra melhorar o exemplo ? coloca um html também

Comment: É que fiz uma animação com JS, quando o scrooll vai até um ponto ele aplica o CSS com essa animação, mas a animação passa do key 100% ele não pára em 1px de margin-top volta para os -70px; basicamente o HTML é algo `<div class="mostramenu"><nav>...</nav></div>`

Comment: Tem uma ferramenta no site que é possível colocar seu código html,css  e js para que ele seja executado e nós possamos ver.. clique em editar e da uma olhada nas ferramentas de edição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma saída é especificar quantas vezes a animação vai ocorrer:

```
animation-iteration-count: 1
```

### Em funcionamento:

```css
* {position:relative}

div {width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff9}

.mostramenu {
  animation: desce 2s;
  -webkit-animation: desce 2s;
  -moz-animation: desce 2s;
  -o-animation: desce 2s;
}

#d1 {
  position:absolute;left:50px;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#d2 {
  position:absolute;left:200px;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:1;
}

#d3 {
  position:absolute;left:350px;
  animation-iteration-count:5;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:5;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:5;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:5;
}


@keyframes desce {
  0%   { margin-top: -70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 1px;   }
}
```

```html
<div class="mostramenu" id="d1">Infinite</div>
<div class="mostramenu" id="d2">1x</div>
<div class="mostramenu" id="d3">5x</div>
```

### Usando a sintaxe curta:

```css
* {position:relative}

div {width:100px;height:100px;background:#ff9}


#d1 {
  position:absolute;left:50px;
  animation: desce 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: desce 2s infinite;
  -moz-animation: desce 2s infinite;
  -o-animation: desce 2s infinite;
}

#d2 {
  position:absolute;left:200px;
  animation: desce 2s 1;
  -webkit-animation: desce 2s 1;
  -moz-animation: desce 2s 1;
  -o-animation: desce 2s 1;
}

#d3 {
  position:absolute;left:350px;
  animation: desce 2s 5;
  -webkit-animation: desce 2s 5;
  -moz-animation: desce 2s 5;
  -o-animation: desce 2s 5;
}


@keyframes desce {
  0%   { margin-top: -70px; }
  100% { margin-top: 1px;   }
}
```

```html
<div class="mostramenu" id="d1">Infinite</div>
<div class="mostramenu" id="d2">1x</div>
<div class="mostramenu" id="d3">5x</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo... é assim? `.mostramenu
{
    animation: desce 2s;
    -webkit-animation: desce 2s;
    
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
} `

Comment: @JosiasViskoo tem duas demonstrações na resposta, uma usando a propriedade em separado, e a outra agregando a contagem no animate.

Comment: Muito bom, estou testando... já publico aqui o resultado... obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É... resolvi o problema, na verdade como estava utilizando javascript para animar algumas partes isso deu um pequeno BUG porque removia e adiciona a classe CSS, e isso é claro que ia dar um bug, mas o código acima funciona perfeitamente sem o java que eu tive o problema! blz?